# Setting Environment variable using ANT scripts

Tags: java, ant, environment-variables, exec

I have set my ANT_HOME to older version of ANT for my compilation of Java projects.

For my deployment of other applications to server machines, I have another ANT location called ANT2.

Before deployment of files, I would like to set my ANT_HOME to ANT2 and for this purpose I have the following ANT script

```
<target name="run">
     <exec executable="cmd" failonerror="true">
            <env key="ANT_HOME" value="D:\apps\apache-ant-1.8.4"/>
            <arg value="/c"/>
        </exec>
        <property environment="env"/>
    <echo message="${env.ANT_HOME}"/>
</target>
```

However when I execute the above, my ANT home doesn't change to `D:\apps\apache-ant-1.8.4` instead ANT_HOME displays as `D:\apps\old\ant`

What am I doing wrong and how could I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code is not executed in child process

> echo message="${env.ANT_HOME}"

so it shows ANT_HOME from current environment (which is not set to D:\apps\apache-ant-1.8.4). You should print ANT_HOME from inside cmd app to see its value in child process.

Comment: Yes you are right, what it seems to be that with `exec` value of ANT_HOME is changed and once EXEC scope is finished, value is getting changed back to its original.

Comment: If there is a way to keep exec scope within `<scp>` and `<sshexec>` then it would have been good as my major chunk of script is within these.